ASP.NET Core MVC ActionArguments of ActionExecutingContext always empty
I have this function in a controller:
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LoggedInAttribute))]
[HttpPut("bio")]
public ActionResult<string> ChangeBio(string UserId, string Bio)
{ 
    // ... 
}

And this attribute class:
public class LoggedInAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // ...

    public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Here the `filterContext.ActionArguments.Keys.Count` is always zero
        // no matter what action it's called from
    }

    // ...
}

Why could this be happening?
This puzzles me the most, in one field it sees the parameters and in the other it doesn't?

The reason why the ActionArguments of ActionExecutingContext always empty is is  due to the way the parameters are being passed in the HttpPut request.
If you just send the parameter by using querystring like below , then you will directly get the parameter inside the ActionArguments.
Url:
https://localhost:7072/bio?UserId=1&Bio=2
Result:

If you want to bind with the form data which send inside the request body, you should  add [FromForm] tag.
Notice: This is according how you send the request, if your request content is Json, you should use [FromBody].
Codes as below:
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(LoggedInAttribute))]
    [HttpPut("bio")]
    public ActionResult<string> ChangeBio([FromForm]string UserId, [FromForm]string Bio)
    {
        // ... 

        return "TEST";
    }

Request:

Result:

